# Android Studio: "Ok" button disabled in "Create new AVD" window

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual, device, android-virtual-device

I downloaded and installed the latest Android Studio version which is 0.8.6 (beta) and I was stuck while trying to create a new Android Virtual Device.
I tried to follow these steps: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html but looks like the CPU/ABI is unavailable when I pick one of the types mentioned in that document (Android Wear Square/Round) and the skins named AndroidWearRound or AndroidWearSquare are also unavailble.
Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty likely that you forgot to download one of the system-images, either `ARM EABI v7a` or `Intel x86`.
See the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The above example works ... however even after downloading all required packages the button was deactivated. Later by fluke I realized it also gets deactivated when there is a space in AVD name.
Though AVD manager never complain about it.

Comment: seriously this thing happened to me and i happen to download all the unnecessary stuff

Comment: Wow, that was a great point to be noted. It helped me out in creating my own virtual device. +1

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure to select only one choice in the Emulation Options. If both are selected OK will be disabled. (IMO:  A radio button would have been a better option.)

Comment: This worked. I don't how google can bungle up validation and showing user error messages on such a tool. They can do better